# IntelliJ 2017.2 - cannot open settings dialog

Tags: intellij-idea

After updating Intellij 2017.1 to 2017.2, I cannot open settings anymore.

No error are shown in the UI. I also tried running IntelliJ from the command line, nothing either.

I read that the plugins can be the source of the issue. Here is the list of my enabled plugins :

`BashSupport (1.6.10.172)
Bytecode Viewer (0.1)
CFML Support (3.53)
CoffeeScript (2.0)
Copyright (8.1)
Coverage (172.3317.76)
CSS Support (172.3317.76)
Database Tools and SQL (172.3317.76)
DSM Analysis (1.0.0)
EditorConfig (172.3317.76)
Emma (172.3317.76)
Git Integration (8.1)
GitHub (172.3317.76)
Haml (172.3317.76)
HTML Tools (2.0)
I18n for Java (172.3317.76)
IntelliLang (8.0)
J2ME (1.0)
Java Bytecode Decompiler (172.3317.76)
JavaFX (1.0)
JavaScript Debugger (1.0)
JavaScript Intention Power Pack (0.9.4)
JavaScript Support (1.0)
Lines Sorter (1.0.1)
Markdown support (172.3317.76)
NixIDEA (0.2.0.1)
NodeJS (172.3317.8)
NSIS plugin (0.2.0)
Plugin DevKit (1.0)
Properties Support (172.3317.76)
QuirksMode (172.3317.76)
Refactor-X (2.01)
Remote Hosts Access (0.1)
REST Client (172.3317.76)
Ruby (2017.2.20170717)
Sass support (172.3317.76)
Settings Repository (172.3317.76)
Spy-js (172.3317.76)
SSH Remote Run (0.1)
Stylus support (999.999)
Task Management (1.0)
Terminal (0.1)
Time Tracking (1.0)
UML Support (1.0)
W3C Validators (2.0)
XPathView + XSLT Support (4)
XSLT-Debugger (1.4)
YAML (172.3317.76)
ZKM-Unscramble (1.0)`

Any idea ?

Comment: Check [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085) for exceptions to find and disable the offending plug-in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @CrazyCoder answer, I found the offending plugin : NixIDEA.

There is an issue in the Github repo already : https://github.com/NixOS/nix-idea/issues/10